# Understanding the output of sensors command in Ubuntu

Tags: overheating, temperature, intel-nuc

I have a remote ubuntu NUC installed at client location. Below is the output of `sensors` command:

```
pch_skylake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +60.5°C  

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:       -263.2°C  

iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +41.0°C  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +90.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +75.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +90.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

Can anyone please explain what is `pch_skylake-virtual-0`, `acpitz-virtual-0` and `iwlwifi_1-virtual-0`. This is an intel NUC with `i7` and `16gb` RAM but I am unable to understand why the temperature is `+90*c`. This NUC is placed in server room with room temperature as `24*C` so temperature should not be `+90*C`. How can I reduce its temperature. Can anyone please give some good suggestions.? Please help. Thanks

Below is the screenshot of `top` command

[image]

Another screenshot of top command:

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and show me the `top` command.

Comment: @heynnema add the screenshot of output of `top` command. Please review

Comment: The CPU temps will always be higher than the room temp, but 90.0°C is too high. The `top` command shows that +100% of your CPU is running sqlserver and dotnet. If that CPU usage STAYS that high, that explains why the temp is so high. Review your configuration/usage of those two apps.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks, I will see if I can reduce the CPU load to cool down the CPU temperature.

Comment: You can also decrease CPU temperature by reducing the maximum CPU frequency. Power verses CPU frequency is highly non-linear at upper frequencies. The result would actually be higher reported loads.

Comment: @heynnema I have attached another screenshot of top command where it shows 166% CPU usage for sqlserver but I am confused as how it can be 166%. Can you please explain this.

Comment: Because you have a dual-core processor, each processor can be running at 100%, so that 200% CPU usage is totally possible. What's also concerning is the amount of memory that sqlserver is taking. I'd spend a lot more time trying to figure out if that's normal.